# How to get include_vars variable populated inside Jinja template?

Tags: variables, ansible, jinja2

I have couple of variable files like below:

```
$ cat vars_ip.yml
---
12.1.1.25: TAP1
12.1.1.26: TAP2
11.0.0.26: TAP3
11.0.0.27: TAP4
9.2.2.211: SAT1
9.2.2.212: SAT2
10.7.7.28: SAT3
10.7.7.29: SAT4
9.2.2.213: SAT5
10.7.7.30: SAT6


$ cat vars.yml

---
  layers:
    - name: MY_LAYER
      things_prod:
        - 12.1.1.25
        - 12.1.1.26
      things_dr:
        - 11.0.0.26
        - 11.0.0.27
      bgcolor:
        - '#AED6F1'


    - name: YR_LAYER
      things_prod:
        - 9.2.2.211
        - 9.2.2.212
        - 9.2.2.213
      things_dr:
        - 10.7.7.28
        - 10.7.7.29
        - 10.7.7.30
      bgcolor:
        - '#F9E79F'
```

Here is my playbook:

```
$ cat varloop.yml

---
  - name: variables in Jinja2
    hosts: localhost
    vars_files:
      - vars.yml
      - vars_ip.yml
    gather_facts: no
    tasks:
      - name: Create the Jinja2 based template
        template: src=./varloop.j2 dest=./sync/sync.html
```

Here is my Jinja template file:

```
$ cat varloop.j2  

{% for layer in layers %}
{% for item in layer.things_prod %}
{{ item }} {{ layer.things_dr[loop.index-1] }} var[{{ item }}] var[layer.things_dr[loop.index-1]]
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Current Output:

```
$ cat ./sync/sync.html

12.1.1.25 11.0.0.26 var[12.1.1.25] var[layer.things_dr[loop.index-1]]
12.1.1.26 11.0.0.27 var[12.1.1.26] var[layer.things_dr[loop.index-1]]
9.2.2.211 10.7.7.28 var[9.2.2.211] var[layer.things_dr[loop.index-1]]
9.2.2.212 10.7.7.29 var[9.2.2.212] var[layer.things_dr[loop.index-1]]
9.2.2.213 10.7.7.30 var[9.2.2.213] var[layer.things_dr[loop.index-1]]
```

I need the values from the vars_ip.yml variable file to be populated in the jinja template like below:

My expected output:

```
12.1.1.25 11.0.0.26 TAP1 TAP3
12.1.1.26 11.0.0.27 TAP2 TAP4
9.2.2.211 10.7.7.28 WAS1 WAS3
9.2.2.212 10.7.7.29 WAS2 TAP4
9.2.2.213 10.7.7.30 WAS3 WAS6
```

How to do this?

Comment: `12.1.1.25` and others (probably IP addresses) in the file `vars_ip.yml`  are not [**valid variable names**](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#creating-valid-variable-names).

Comment: @VladimirBotka I have successfully used ip addresses as variable names before in Ansible playbooks. The issue here is how do I read the variables from vars_ip.yml inside of my Jinja template file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Vladimir Botka  I was trying 'n' possible solutions before one actually worked !!

This gets me the value and the IP address is treated as a variable:

```
{% for layer in layers %}
{% for item in layer.things_prod %}
{{ item }} {{ layer.things_dr[loop.index-1] }} {{ vars[item] }} {{ vars[layer.things_dr[loop.index-1]] }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Output:

## cat sync.html

```
12.1.1.25 11.0.0.26 TAP1 TAP3
12.1.1.26 11.0.0.27 TAP2 TAP4
9.2.2.211 10.7.7.28 SAT1 SAT3
9.2.2.212 10.7.7.29 SAT2 SAT4
9.2.2.213 10.7.7.30 SAT5 SAT6
```